# How to use two different outputs of one TV in MODX?

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

I have TV with input type "File". How can i use output of this file few times:
1. in one place as url 
2. in one place as name of this file
3. in one place as size of this file

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - use your tv - `<a href="[[++site_url]][[*myFileTv]]">My File</a>`

2 - use snippet like this -

```
[[!getNameFromPath?&path=`[[*myFileTv]]`]]
```

and code of this snippen is -

```
<?php
$path = $modx->getOption('path', $scriptProperties, '');
$fileName = basename($path);
return $fileName;
```

3 - use another snippet -

```
[[!getSizeFromPath?&path=`[[*myFileTv]]`]]
```

which code is -

```
<?php
$path = $modx->getOption('path', $scriptProperties, '');
if (!empty($path)) {
    $size = filesize(MODX_BASE_PATH . ltrim($path,'/'));
    $sizes = array(" Bytes", " KB", " MB", " GB", " TB", " PB", " EB", " ZB", " YB");
    if ($size == 0) { 
        return('n/a'); 
    } else {
        return (round($size/pow(1024, ($i = floor(log($size, 1024)))), 2) . $sizes[$i]); 
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't work for me
shows "a>" as name and "n/a" as size @vasis

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a snippet to output the parameter you want.. something like:

[[!outputMyFile? &attribute=`name` &tv=`[[*myTvValue]]`]]

where the snippet will do your processing on the TV value [the file name]  and output the appropriate attribute you want.